# What is finally entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Let's say that a layman reads the definitions of entropy with the chronological order of their formulation.

First definition: heat weighted by temperature inverted.

Second definition: logarithm of possible microstates

Third definition: hidden but conserved information as we go from the world of Avogadro numbers to the macroscopic world that we sense and live.

Of course all definitions are equally true. All these definitions belong to the realm of thermodynamics, they explain thermodynamic concepts as temperature and heat. If this is the case how can I think or prove the Clausius theorem by means of the concept of hidden information or the formula of Boltzmann?

In other words, what all these definitions have in common?

Comment: To me all it means is that the concept of entropy can be extended to cover different situations, there is no other way to teach the extent and  importance of the entropy concept  except by following the pattern you have outlined. If you look up entropy  in Wikipedia, there is no overall definition, you get asked what area of physics you want to find out about. I would not agree that the first definition is equally true or of much use until T is strictly defined, which needs the ideas behind the second definition. So one definition for TD and one for information?

Comment: The issue is that there are a lot of "entropies", e.g. Renyi entropy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy. Although is a blunt definition, you can say that __Entropies quantify the diversity, uncertainty, or randomness of a system.__ Perhaps it also help you to read the discussion of Boltzmann vs Loschmidt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loschmidt's_paradox.

Comment: You can also consider its definition in the bag of what is energy or matter? As in physics, you don't really care "what is", but how you use it (what is it's more a philosophical problem).

Comment: @user2820579 What is entropy is not equivalent i suppose to what is matter. Entropy has a sound definition in statistical mechanics, as I see it that means it is an "emergent" concept very different from energy and matter

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying that they are equivalent. I was taking examples of concepts that we use, but we do not exactly know what they are. On the other hand, the definition of entropy in statistical mechanics it's not the most general, and certainly in ecology (or in quantum information) you can use the Renyi entropy as a sound definition of entropy.

Comment: @user2820579 If except myself, nobody really knows what it is that means maybe measurements are correct but physics ( together with chemistry and biology ) is not a science.

Comment: Just because the same word is used to describe different concepts does not mean that those concepts are the same even if they are related. Prime examples are slang usage in the English language, such as "cool", "hot", and most four letter words...

Comment: @hyportnex very funny but all these definitions are describing the same thing

Comment: I disagree that they describe the *same* thing. Enormous amount of rather sterile work was expended on finding *useful* relationship between thermodynamic and information entropies besides the obvious and superficial analogies. From the information transmission side I believe the result is absolutely nothing...

Comment: @hyportnex If this is this case  then one of the two definitions is not scientific

Comment: This is not about being scientific or not, it is about the usage of and the evolution of usage of the same word to describe different or similar but not identical concepts/quantities. The thermodynamic entropy of Clauius is a perfectly fine concept without *any* microscopic interpretation; steam generators of your electric plant work very well without the Boltzmann or Gibbs entropy, the same is true for any communications system and its error correcting code that is designed using Shannon's theory. These are all very scientific but use the same central concept called: entropy.

Comment: @hyportnex I really want to convince you that internal combustion engines don't work on any thermodynamic cycle. I diden't mention Shannon entropy. Hidden information is a thermodynamic concept, it explains the emergence of heat, pressure etc